# Video field in widget required in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a widget with different non mandatory fields. Every "required: false" works great, except for the video field : when submitting, the field becomes red if empty.

The index.js file :

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Hero',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'image',
      type: 'attachment',
      label: 'Image',
      required: false
    },
    {
      name: 'video',
      type: 'video',
      label: 'Video',
      required: false
    },
    {
      name: 'description',
      type: 'string',
      label: 'Description',
      required: false
    },
  ],
};
```

If I provide a youtube video url, for example, it works fine. But if I don't want a video, I can't save the widget. My question : does the "video" field type manages "required: false" or is there a trick to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself : the video type is a module, containing an input with required=true.

So, unless modifying (extending ?) the code from Apostrophe, a solution is to create a second widget to handle the video type. That is what I did.

And then in my 'home' view, I added an area containing the 2 widgets, but with a limit of 1, forcing the user to create only of the 2 widgets (picture or video) :

```
{{ 
   apos.area(data.page, 'body', { 
       widgets: {
         'hero-video': {},
         'hero-picture': {}
       },
       limit: 1
   })
}}
```

Comment: This is a good workaround for your situation, but feel free to open a github issue about video fields always being required. That would be a bug.